# if previous value in one column and next value in another column meet a condition, add 1 into another column using r

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have data like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), time = c(1834, 4809, 18, 
333, 387), nh_source = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), admi_source = c(19, 
19, 85, 19, 88), disdest = c(85, 29, 56, 85, 39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

and I want to group the ids and check if the previous value in column disdest is 56 or 85 and the next value in column admisorc is 19, then add 1 to column nh_source column.I want the df to look like this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), time = c(1834, 4809, 18, 
333, 387), nh_source2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0), admi_source = c(19, 
19, 85, 19, 88), disdest = c(85, 29, 56, 85, 39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the logical condition with `lag` after grouping by 'id' and add it to the 'nh_source' (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(id) %>% 
     mutate(nh_source = nh_source + 
             (admi_source == 19 & lag(disdest) %in% c(56, 85))) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  id time nh_source admi_source disdest
1  1 1834         0          19      85
2  1 4809         1          19      29
3  2   18         1          85      56
4  2  333         1          19      85
5  2  387         0          88      39
```